# Add CSS attributes to Symfony form labels?

Tags: css, forms, symfony1, label, symfony-forms

I try to add some css attributes to labels in my custom sfForm but I can't achieve it.

In my custom class `myForm extends sfForm`, I create all textfields dynamically:

```
public function configure()
{
    $widgetFixtures = array();
    foreach ($fixtures as $fixture) {  
     $widgetFixtures[$fixture->getId()] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(  
            array('label' => $fixture->getTeamNameDom()),  
            // I would like to add something like: array('class' => $fixture->getCSS()),
            array('value' => $fixture->getScore1(), 'readonly' => 'readonly')
            );
    }
    $this->setWidgets($widgetFixtures);
}
```

I tried to format the rendering with `setFormFormatterName` but without success.

Note: I can't use `renderLabel($value, $attributes = array())` in the template because I get the CSS class from the DB (as you may have seen, I have to use: $fixture->getCSS()).

Could someone shed my light?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved it.
I took both suggestions from johnwards and richsage and put them together :
 *"This sort of stuff should be handled in the view/action."*
 *"Access to the options/attributes passed to the Widget itself."*

First, I add the CSS class to the input itself (even if I will not use it).

In my custom class `myForm extends sfForm`,

```
foreach ($fixtures as $fixture) {    
     $widgetFixtures[$fixture->getId()] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(  
         array('label' => $fixture->getTeamNameDom()),  
         array('value' => $fixture->getScore1(), 
               'readonly' => 'readonly',  
               'class' => $fixture->getCSS())  
         );  
}
```

Then, in the template, instead of using `echo $form;`, I add the CSS class to the label as shown below:

```
foreach ($form as $widgetId => $widget) {  
    ...
    $labelClass = $widget->getWidget()->getAttribute('class');  
    echo '<td>'.$widget->renderLabel(null, array('class' => $labelClass)).'</td>';  
    ...
}
```

Maybe it is not the best way to solve this issue but it works.

Thanks all for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do seems possible but your greyed out syntax seems a little off. Try this:

```
    $widgetFixtures[$fixture->getId()] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(  
        array('label' => $fixture->getTeamNameDom()),  
        array('class' => $fixture->getCSS()),
        array('value' => $fixture->getScore1(), 'readonly' => 'readonly')
    );
```

... or check "The sfWidgetForm Base Class" section here: http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/A-Widgets

Comment: sfWidgetFormInputText only accept 2 parameters $options=array() and $attributes=array(). 
I already had a look at symfony website and cannot found any info regarding putting css attributes to labels...
Functions like "setLabel($name, $value)" doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute needs to be passed in as an array in the second parameter for all form widgets.

```
$this->setWidget('foo', new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('class','fooclass'));
```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong but I think this syntax will add the CSS class to the input text. My issue is to assign CSS class to its label.

Comment: Ah no sorry, early morning my mistake. You are not going to be able to do that easily when customising the form. You are starting to get a bit too complicated for the form framework. This sort of stuff should be handled in the view/action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the widget class if you want to add CSS to labels - specifically the methods that render the label.  You could then do something like

```
$foo = new myWidgetFormInputText(array("myCSSClass" => $fixture->getCSS()));
```

and then override your `renderLabel()` method or similar in your widget.  Your widget will have access to the options you pass in - in the above example `myCSSClass` is the option key.  You can then apply this class value to your widget's label.

Comment: Widgets don't have a renderLabel method, those are on the form fields. http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_2/sfFormField Lots of really knarly stuff to get this to work where it would be simpler to do it in the action/view

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier than that. Just apply CSS to the label for tag...

```
label[for=payment_cardNumber]
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```